# Searching for number after a specific word that does not immediately precede the number

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use a pattern to search for a Zip Code within a string. I cannot get it to work correctly.

A sample of the inputLine is

```
What is the weather in 75042?
```

What I am trying to use for a pattern is

```
public String getZipcode(String inputLine) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*weather.*([0-9]+).*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

        if (matcher.find()) {

            return matcher.group(1).toString();
        }

        return "Zipcode Not Found.";

    }
```

If I am looking to only get 75002, what do I need to change? This only outputs the last digit in the number, 2. I am terribly confused and I do not completely understand the Javadocs for the Pattern class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.*weather.*([0-9]+).*` pattern grabs the whole line with the first `.*` and backtracks to find `weather`, and if it finds it, it grabs the line portion after the words to the end of line with the subsequent `.*` pattern and backtracks again to find the last digit and the only one digit is stored in Capturing group 1 since one digit satisfies the `[0-9]+` pattern. The last `.*` just consumes the line to its end.

You may solve the issue by just using `".*weather.*?([0-9]+).*"` (making the second `.*` lazy), but since you are using `Matcher#find()`, you can use a simpler regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("weather\\D*(\\d+)");
```

And after getting a match, retrieve the value with `matcher.group(1)`.

**See the** [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/TsIuuS/1).

**Pattern details**

- `weather` - a `weather` word
- `\\D*` - 0+ chars other than digits
- `(\\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/nAK5Dz):

```
String inputLine = "What is the weather in 75042?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("weather\\D*(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // => 75042
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason is because the `.*` matches the first digits and let only one left for your capturing group, you have to throw it away

A more simple pattern can be used here : `\D+(\d+)\D+` which means

- *some non-digits   `\D+`, then some digits to capture  `(\d+)`, then some non-digits  `\D+`*

```
public String getZipcode(String inputLine) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D+(\\d+)\\D+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1).toString();
    }
    return "Zipcode Not Found.";
}
```

[***`Workable Demo`***](https://ideone.com/uoy8pa)

Answer (score 4):

Spaces are missing in your regex (\s). You can use \s* or \s+ based on your data

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("weather\\s*\\w+\\s*(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
```

Comment: You need to use double backslashes inside Java string literals to define a literal backslash that serves as a regex escape char. The current `Pattern.compile("weather\s*\w+\s*(\d+)")` won't compile in Java.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My bad! Updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your middle `.*` is too greedy and eats away 7500. One easy fix is to add a space before your regexp: `.*weather.* ([0-9]+).*` or even use `\\s`. But the best is to use non-greedy version of `.*?` so regexp should be `.*weather.*?([0-9]+).*`

Answer (score 3):

I think all you need is `\\d+`

```
public String getZipcode(String inputLine) throws Exception {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group();
    }

    //A good practice is to throw an exception if no result found
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Zipcode Not Found.");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In regular expressions operators that have no upper bound (*, +) are **greedy**.

There were already perfect solutions suggested.
I'm just adding one that is very close to your's and addresses the problem in a more isolated way:

If you use the regex

`".*weather.*?([0-9]+).*"` ... instead of ...

`".*weather.*([0-9]+).*"`

... your solution will work perfectly well. The '**?**' after the asterisk instructs the regex compiler to treat the asterisk as non-greedy.

Greedy means consuming as many characters as possible (from left to right) while still allowing the remainder of the regex to match.

Non-greedy means consuming as few characters as possible while still allowing the remainder of the regex to match.

Comment: You do not have to add this solution because I already mentioned it in my post. See *You may solve the issue by just using `".*weather.*?([0-9]+).*"` (making the second `.*` lazy),*. However, this is too inefficient. And [Damir's answer also features the same pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186537/3832970).